# Core Data Entity Object in Object Library

Tags: xcode, core-data, xcode4

I recently downloaded Xcode 4.0. After I installed it, Xcode downloaded the Core Data Framework.  The version I have installed is 102.1. 
I built a test application in Xcode 3.2 and was able to place a Core Data Entity in my Main Window. 
 I rewrote the application in Xcode 4.0 but cannot find a Core Data Entity in the Object Library. I am trying to discover if the Framework was not loaded properly or that for some reason is no Core Data Entity in the Xcode 4.0 Object Library. I can open my xcdatamodel file and edit it.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your installation. The feature isn't available in Xcode 4 at the moment and there is no indication whether its coming back or not.

I found it useful as well. The best thing to do is to have an installation of Xcode 3 on your system that you can use to create nibs that you want to use that object in.

https://devforums.apple.com/thread/77106?tstart=0